# What's the best way to sort some items in a list in one way, and the rest, another way?

Tags: java, sorting

Say I do a search which returns a list of objects

```
{ age: 5, color: Yellow, eggs: 2 }
{ age: 3, color: White,  eggs: 5 }
{ age: 4, color: Brown,  eggs: 9 }
{ age: 2, color: Green,  eggs: 4 }
{ age: 3, color: Red,    eggs: 1 }
{ age: 1, color: Blue,   eggs: 6 }
```

I would like to output them all, but in a particular order.
If age is 3, I want these items first, sorted on most amount of eggs.
Then I want the rest of the items sorted alphabetically on color.

So the sorted list would be

```
|   3's: eggs   |    rest: alphabetically on color    |
 White  -  Red  -  Blue  -  Brown  -  Green  -  Yellow
```

What is the best way to do this sorting, preferably without creating temporary lists?

Can it be done using a single Comparator, or using streams maybe?

Comment: If you consider this the natural order of the elements, I'd have the class implement the `Comparable` interface ant properly implement the `compareTo()` method

Comment: *Can it be done using a single Comparator*: yes, but you need to write it. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a single, kind of messy, Comparator. The idea is:

```
int compare(myType obj1, myType obj2)
{
    // first compare age
    if (obj1.age == 3)
    {
        if (obj2.age == 3)
        {
            // ages are both 3, so count eggs
            return obj1.eggs.compareTo(obj2.eggs);
        }
        // age 3 sorts before everything else
        return -1;
    }
    else if (obj2.age == 3)
    {
        // if obj2.age is 3, and obj1.age isn't 3,
        // then obj1 is greater than obj2
        return 1;
    }

    // compare color
    return obj1.color.compareTo(obj2.color);
}
```

Please excuse any syntactical mistakes; my Java is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8, `Comparator` has a few helpful static methods:

```
new AgeComparator().thenComparingInt(MyObj::getEggs).thenComparing(new ColorComparator());
```

Not sure what your class looks like - is that what you are asking for?

In general, I also like Apache Commons' [CompareToBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/CompareToBuilder.html) for combining comparisions, but in your case it seems too limited.

Comment: I don't think that will do what he wants. That will sort by age, and within the same age it'll sort by number of eggs, and then by color. So the output using your suggestion would put the items with age 1 and 2 ahead of 3.